# changing image source from R.drawable to external source like SD card for CoverFlow

Tags: android, external, drawable, sd-card, coverflow

I was wondering why my images don't show up on the coverflow. Any Ideas?  this is for a coverflow that is based off of the android gallery app.  it was taking images from the R.drawable as the source. and i changed it to taking the images off of the SD card.  and i don't know how to use the code recommended by the author.

here is the original authors example on how to take code from external source:

```
            //Use this code if you want to load from resources
         ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext);
         i.setImageResource(mImageIds[position]);
         i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
         i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);            
         return i;
```

and here is how i tried it:
first commenting out the code of the R.drawable references;

```
        public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
      int mGalleryItemBackground;
      private Context mContext;

      private FileInputStream fis;


      private Integer[] mImageIds = {

     //     R.drawable.pic01,
       //   R.drawable.pic02,
        //    R.drawable.pic03,
        //    R.drawable.pic04,
        //    R.drawable.pic05,
        //    R.drawable.pic06,
        //    R.drawable.pic07,
        //    R.drawable.pic08,
        //    R.drawable.pic09
      };



    private ImageView[] mImages;


           public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ImageView i = new ImageView(mContext.getApplicationContext());
            imagecursor.moveToPosition(position);
            int id = imagecursor.getInt(image_column_index);
            i.setImageURIUri.withAppendedPathMediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, ""+ id));
            i.setLayoutParams(new CoverFlow.LayoutParams(130, 130));
            i.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.MATRIX);         

            return i;

        //return mImages[position];
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the original code but like this:

```
i.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(PATH_TO_YOUR_IMAGE_FILE_ON_SDCARD));
```

You can name your images files with numbers:
image_1.png, image_2.png ... and then use :

```
i.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile("image_" + position));
```

Or you can predecode all the Images to an array...